# how can I get these two lines to print on different lines in the cmd console

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

How can I get the code when I step through it to print these two different lines onto different lines in the console, cmd, instead of on the same line.

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall

GetStdHandle proto :dword
WriteConsoleA proto :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword
ExitProcess proto :dword

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11

.data

    Title db "Basic Calculator",0
    Intruct1 db "please type your expresion",0
    outputHandle DWORD ?
    bytes_written dd ?
    bytes_written2 dd ?

.code
main proc
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov outputHandle, eax

    invoke WriteConsoleA, outputHandle, addr Title, 20, addr bytes_written, 0

    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov outputHandle, eax

    invoke WriteConsoleA, outputHandle, addr Intruct1, 45, addr bytes_written2, 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp

end
```

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way would be to add carriage return linefeed to each string. E.g.:

```
Title db "Basic Calculator",0x0d, 0x0a, 0
Intruct1 db "please type your expresion",0x0d, 0x0a,0
```

You will likely need to update the characters to write count by +2 as well. Not familiar with those `invoked` calls you are making.

Linux,OSX,BSD, etc. only require `0x0a`.